# "Shadow insert is nil. File a bug on UICollectionView!" error when drag&dropping a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I drag & drop a cell in a UICollectionView, sometimes, this crash happens:

> Assertion failure in -[_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController _beginDragAndDropInsertingItemAtIndexPath:], _UICollectionViewDragAndDropController.m:615
>
> Shadow insert is nil. File a bug on UICollectionView!

What can I do to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to update your cells properly (using `reloadData`/`insertItems`/`reloadItems`/`deleteItems`/`reloadSections`) to reflect any changes in the data source.